# How to specify a contentdatabase name while creating a webapplicatoin using powershell in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint, powershell, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

How can i specify a name to SharePoint content database while creating a SharePoint web application using power shell

I can create a web application using power shell but haven't seen an option for specifying a name to the content database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at the [technet documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607931%28v=office.14%29.aspx) there is a -DatabaseName switch on the New-SPWebApplication command.